# Codeigniter: Pagination wont show up

Tags: codeigniter, search, pagination

First of all I'm a newbie of Codeigniter.

I'm having problems in showing the pagination links. But when i use search the pagination shows up. Then another problem pops up, when i search there will be links of pagination, when I click the links it doesnt show the paginated search but show the whole non search results.

Controller:

```
    public function info($offset=0)
{       

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $count = $this->ticketing_mdl->count_all_ticket();




    $limit = 4;

    $config['base_url'] = "/ticketing/index.php/ticketing/info";
    $config['total_rows'] = $count;
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;

    $config['num_links'] = $limit;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['ticket_list'] = $this->ticketing_mdl->get_all_ticket($limit, $offset);

    $this->load->view('ticketing/header');
    $this->load->view('ticketing/left_menu');
    $this->load->view('ticketing/info',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
function get_all_ticket($limit,$page)
{


    if($this->input->get('search')){
        $match = $this->input->get("search");
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_ticketing.tr_ticket WHERE requested_by LIKE '%$match%' limit $page,$limit";
        return $this->db->query($sql);
    }else{
    $match = $this->input->get("search");
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM db_contract.bs_contract WHERE contract_tag LIKE '%$match%'";
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_ticketing.tr_ticket  limit $page";
    return $this->db->query($sql);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:
`return $this->db->query($sql);` to
`return $this->db->query($sql)->result();`
Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my first problem with showing the pagination. now the problem is when i search a keyword the pagination shows up. but when i click the pagination links it does not continues the search result pagination

Controller

```
if($this->input->get('search')){
    $count = $this->ticketing_mdl->count_all_ticket();
    $config['total_rows'] = $count;
    }else{
    $this->db->where('is_valid','1');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('db_ticketing.tr_ticket');

    }
```